# Transform an HttpWebResponse to an object c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm pretty new on programming, so please keep that in mind when seeing my post.

I'm using this code to get an response from an webserver (I'm not hosting the server):

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        var postData = "user=user";
        postData += "&ordernr[]=1234234";
        postData += "&ordernr[]=23425";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString;
```

The string that I receive

```
{
    "Transport":{
    "New York": "Bus",
    "Miami": "Airplane"
    }
}
```

I want to translate this to an object, so I can read out city and what sort or transport.
How do I do that ?

Comment: This is a Json string. If you want to *parse* this Json string use Json.NET. Create a class that matches this schema and use eg `Json.Convert<MyTransportClass>(thatString)` to parse it

Comment: Like I said I´m very new on programming, how could a such class look ?